# Text misalignment in vector graphic format export

Tags: graphics, vector

In converting a number of old notebooks into a format for e-readers, Mathematica has some issues with vector formats.  SVG export would have been ideal to use, but the exporter fails to recognize, for instance, subscripts given in Text[] statements as part of the pictures; instead, the glyphs are shown at full size.  The text seems to fail in other ways to stay the same after export.  The same problem occurs with PDF, SVG and EPS export.

The notebook that I'm trying to transform was produced in Mathematica 5.2.  This older version of the software succeeds perfectly in exporting via EPS.  Perhaps rendering all the graphics again in the new kernel would solve the problem, but I'd prefer to avoid doing this--as there are 500+ notebooks to convert--with no guarantee that even the input cells still operate without changes.

Any thoughts on why the old version 5.2 does a decent job, but version 11 can't do it?  Would pictures showing the difference help to debug the problem?

Comment: Do the same problems occur if you print to PDF or postscript?